# Can Cortex-A57 dual-issue 128-bit neon instructions?

Tags: assembly, arm, pipeline

The Cortex-A57 Optimization Guide states that most integer instructions operating on 128-bit vector data can be dual-issued (Page 24, integer basic F0/F1, logical F0/F1, execution throughput 2).

However with our internal (synthetic) benchmarks, throughput seems to be limited to exactly 1 128-bit neon integer instruction, even when there is plenty of instruction parallelism available (the benchmark was written with the intention to test whether 128-bit neon instructions can be dual-issued, so this is something we took care). When mixing 50% 128-bit with 50% 64-bit instructions, we were able to achieve 1.25 instructions per clock (only neon integer arith, no loads/stores).

Are there special measures which have to be taken in order to get dual-issue throughput when using 128-bit ASIMD/Neon instructions?

Thx, Clemens

Comment: There are a fair few instruction that can only issue down one pipe, and also quite a number where the Q form has a cycle more latency/less throughput than the D form - what's the _actual_ code (disassembly) in question?

Comment: The code in question looks e.g. like:

.loop:
vand q2, q3, q2
vand q3, q4, q3
vand q4, q3, q4
vand q5, q6, q5       
vand q6, q7, q6
vand q7, q8, q7
vand q8, q9, q8 
vand q9, q10, q9
vand q10, q11, q10
vand q11, q12, q11
vand q12, q13, q12
vand q13, q14, q13
vand q14, q15, q14
vand q15, q1, q15
subs r0, r0, #1
bne .loop

Comment: Don't paste code in a comment. You can edit your question for that.

Comment: You have `vand q4, q3, q4` in your code instead of `vand q4, q5, q4`. This will add a dependency on the previous instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it was a typo.

I benchmarked again and with the code at http://pastebin.com/AQCN5uuM I get roughly an IPC of ~1.5. I really wonder what is going wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In real code, not all instruction results will be written to the register file, instead they will pass through forwarding paths. If you mix dependent and independent instructions in your code, you may see higher IPC.

The A57 optimisation guide states that late-forwarding occurs for chains of multiply-accumulate instructions, so maybe something like this will dual-issue.

```
.loop
    vmla.s16 q0,q0,q1
    vmla.s16 q0,q0,q2
    vmla.s16 q0,q0,q3
    vmla.s16 q4,q4,q1
    vmla.s16 q4,q4,q2
    vmla.s16 q4,q4,q3
    ...etc
```

Answer (score 2):

According to ARM support the reason seems to be that the NEON register file only supports 3x 64-bit write ports.

So although the NEON ALUs are capable of processing 2x128-bit vectors, the register file is not capable of consuming the results ... what a (very) strange design descision.

Comment: I have verified this limit in practice through extensive benchmarking, and observed the same behavior in the Cortex-A72 core (BCM2711 CPU used in the Raspberry Pi 4). Additionally, although you speak of "NEON register file", this appears to be a global limit, not NEON-specific: a loop of multiple copies of fully independent 2 NEON + 1 scalar instruction gives even worse performance than 2 NEON instructions alone.